# Can i use ternary operator on left of assignment operator?

Tags: php

Like

```
(true ? $a : $b) = 5;
```

Or

```
(true ? &$a : &$b) = 5;
```

Or

```
&(true ? $a : $b) = 5;
```

("It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.")

Comment: wait.. why would you expect you could? `(boolean result) = 5` - you can't set a condition output to a value .. o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve quite the same result using, **instead of the variable itself** as return value of the ternary expression, the **name of the variable**.

`(true ? $a : $b)` won't return the variables, but their content.

This can be achieved like this :

```
<?php
${true ? "a": "b"} = 5;

echo $a; // outputs 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it like this.

```
$val = 5;
true ? $a = $val : $b = $val;
```

Comment: Live Demo : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ee97e6e619d9dce40438c3160cf96ffc3f73474

Comment: I'm really struggling to see what the point is though... won't `$a` in this example **always** be assigned `$val` since it's always truthy? The right-side of the ternary will never get *hit*..?

Comment: @CD001:  `(condition) ? condition_true : condition_false` I assume whatever condition he is checking is true for one situation. Condition would not be just `true`.

Comment: Heh - I guess I was reading the code too literally, it said `true` so I assumed that's what the OP was actually doing \*shrugs\* ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, in PHP, all the 3 codes give syntax error.

Comment: as far as I know, in all languages it provides a syntax error. Assignment is `variable = value`. variable is always a variable (well, could be a pointer, a property too) and value is always a value or an expression

Comment: @Cid This is allowed in C++ : `*(condition ? a : b) = c;`